# how to use z3 in python to solve smt question

Tags: python, pycharm, smt

I have some problem in using python's package z3 to solve some smt question

my teacher told me to input: z3 km_test.smt in terminal of pycharm,but I received :

usage: z3 [-h] [--s3-prefix S3_PREFIX] [--filesystem FILESYSTEM] [--snapshot-prefix SNAPSHOT_PREFIX] {backup,restore,status} ...
z3: error: argument subcommand: invalid choice: 'km_test.smt' (choose from 'backup', 'restore', 'status')

who can answer me how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

you're running [z3 for ZFS to AWS S3 backup tool](https://github.com/presslabs/z3), not [z3 theorem prover from Microsoft Research](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3).

if you want to use the later Z3 for python, You should install the Python wrapper for Z3 for the latest release from pypi using the command

```
   pip install z3-solver
```